# Installing and enabling python 3 with Chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to install python with chef this is the runbook

```
sudo yum -y install centos-release-scl
sudo yum -y install rh-python36
sudo scl enable rh-python36
```

The 4th step requires python 3. When I do this manually it works as expected, how ever when i do it via chef it still thinks it's python 2.7 therefore it fails on the 4th step. How do I get around this?

```
execute "install centos-release-scl" do
    command "sudo yum -y install centos-release-scl"
    action :run
  end

  execute "install rh-python36" do
    command "sudo yum -y install rh-python36"
    action :run
  end

  execute "enable rh-python3" do
    command "sudo scl enable rh-python36 bash"
    action :run
  end

  execute "pip install dd-check-dev" do
    command "pip install 'datadog-checks-dev[cli]'"
    action :run
  end
```

Comment: `scl enable` doesn't work like that, you need to do `scl enable rh-python36 pip install 'datadog-checks-dev[cli]'` as one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [poise-python](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/poise-python) community cookbook. The cookbook allows you to specify which python and pip version you want to use, and allows you to install python packages via pip using the custom resources of the cookbook. Here is sample code block for installing python 3 :

```
python_runtime '3' do
  version 3
  action :install
end
```

And then you can install your package via :

```
python_package 'datadog-checks-dev[cli]'
```

Comment: FYI: The poise-python cookbook is archived https://github.com/poise/poise-python

Comment: Author here, don't use it. I do not maintain any of my Chef stuff anymore due to the hostile actions of Chef Inc.

Comment: Care to elaborate on "hostile actions of Chef Inc."?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are running chef as `root` user, so you should be able to get rid of all the `sudo`s and multipe execute statements and just execute everything in one `execute` or `bash` resource or even better: use the `package` resource for the yum jobs.

As far as I understand `scl enable` either manipulates the shell environment and/or changes symlink directions. In your example you seem to target the `bash` environment, so you probably want to use a `bash` chef resource. Depending on how `scl` works, you may have to provide the ride "flag" attribute.